# How to make method non-override-able

Tags: c++, oop

I am working on a homework and I need to know how(if possible) to make a public method in the base class non-override-able.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    void foo()
    {
        //Do some calculations
        this->bar();
    }
}
class der : public base
{
public:
    virtual void bar() {std::cout<<"Bar\n";}

    //I want to prevent someone from overriding foo method here
    void foo()
    {
        //Do other calculations
    }
}
```

I think that you should be able to do something like this but I don't know how and I couldn't find anything about it online. Sorry for bad english and sorry if I misused the term override, what I want is to not let someone make the `foo` method in the `der` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As `foo` is not virtual I am not sure what you mean by `overriding` as this term is usually applied to `virtual` functions.  To stop virtual functions being overridden in derived classes see [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: You could make `foo` `virtual` and [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: I mean if I create object of type `der` and I call `foo` on it I want to call the `base::foo` version of it

Comment: Declare `base::foo` as both `virtual` and `final`.  `der::foo` will then give a compilation error.

Comment: This sounds like a design mistake. It's not your job to dictate what users of your class do in derived classes. If someone wants to write `der` and provide a member function named `foo` they should be able to do that. After all, they know what their class is supposed to do, and you don't. And their version of `foo` can do whatever it needs to do in addition to calling `base::foo` if that's what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any virtual method can be made final.

```cpp
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0; 
    virtual void g() final {} //this cannot neither overridden nor shadowed in derived class
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void f() final { }
    // void g() {} //compile error
};


struct MoreDerived : Derived
{
    // void f() {}; //compile error
};
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can also make the entire class `final`, so it's impossible to derive from it.